# What's the best way to cite a photo from wikimedia?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm wanting to cite this image [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aLambdaPlaques.jpg), in a piece of work I'm doing. As I'm using `biblatex` what's the best method of citing it?

Comment: I would use the entry type `online`.

Comment: Who would be the author then? Wikimedia?

Comment: Based on this site http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia I say yes ;-)

Comment: In this case, the uploader did not provide any information on the source. You can try to use Google image search to search for copies. In this case, I tried, and I find a lot of copies, but it's not really clear which one is the original source.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I *suggest* the following entry:

```php
@online{pict,
 author  = "Wikimedia Commons",
 title   = "Plaques of Lambda Phages on E. coli XL1-Blue MRF",
 year    = "2007",
 urlseen = "03-02-13",
 url     = "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aLambdaPlaques.jpg",
 note    = "File: \ttfamily{LambdaPlaques.jpg}",
}
```

My suggestion based on the described rules here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia#BibTeX_entry

Comment: What’s with the license? And the user "Madboy” is not needed to be mentioned?

Comment: @Speravir: Is the user the author or only the uploader? I think this isn't clear and so I would use *Wikimedia* as author.

Comment: I don’t know, but **I** would add this name. The more important issue in my eyes is not naming one of the licenses, though.

Comment: I've went with something similar to this, though shouldn't `urlseen` be `urldate` ?

Comment: I think the licence should be added within the citation in the text.
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia

http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/compound-eye/how-to-credit-images-found-in-the-wikimedia-commons/

Comment: I think this is the suggestion how to cite articles, but does this also apply to pictures? Specifically, for pictures, there is often an original source. Although it seems to be unknown in this specific case. In this specific case, someone uploaded the picture without providing any information where the picture is from.

Answer (score 3):

Note that OP's photo is **authorless**, hence the previous answer is tailored only to this photo. The full notice read:

> No machine-readable author provided. Madboy assumed (based on copyright claims).

(Madboy is the user uploads this photo.) In general there's no reason to put Wikimedia Common as the author of the photo.